# select all the records have non empty associated records

Tags: mysql, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I have two models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deals
end
```

and

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now I want to select all those users (through active record query interface) which have non empty array of deals. I want something like this

```
User.select{|u| u.deals != []}
```

I know its very simple but please help me out cause i need it for pagination with will_paginate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not a good approach but it worked for me just adding my answer perhaps it will help any one

```
restaurants_ids = User.all.collect{|u| u.id if (u.role == "restaurant" && !u.deals.empty?)}
@restaurants = User.where(:id=>restaurants_ids).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page=>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can achieve this, but my preffered one is to write scope in your user.rb, like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deals

  scope :with_deals, lambda{
    joins(:deals).uniq
  }
}
```

then calling User.with_deals will return users with non-empty deals only (and you can chain any other resctrictions, because its a relation). So if you use will_paginate, then in your controller you can call:

```
User.with_deals.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

or whatever you need.

Comment: getting empty array for user while i have users with multiple deals.

Comment: The scope is ok, are you sure you have some deals with correct user_id atrribute? And please remember that the paginate part is just an example...

Comment: Any other way by which i can use include or join?